# lemmatizer is not working in python spacy librarary

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot

I am trying to create a small chatbot using spacy library , while i use lemmtizer the code gives  incorrect output. Can someone help me.

Below is my code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
lemmatizer = English.Defaults.create_lemmatizer()
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
lemmatizer = nlp.Defaults.create_lemmatizer()
lemmatizer(u'chuckles', 'Noun')
```

Output

```
['chuckles']
```

The expected output is ***"chuckle"***

Comment: Can someone help me

Comment: A recommended way of using SpaCy is to create a document: `doc=nlp("chuckles"); for word in doc: print(word.lemma_)`.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank You

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, in case someone wants to reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recommended way of using SpaCy is to create a document:

```
doc = nlp("chuckles")
for word in doc:
    print(word.lemma_)
```